# Create corresponding models on ViewSet save

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model that is serialized and created. The Viewset for this is as follows:

```
class OrderViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    depth = 1
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        populate_ing(serializer)
```

Once the user saves and creates the model, I aim to shoot of and call 'populate_ing(xxx)' which takes the model (in this case an order) and creates a number of related objects using a foreign key relationship.

Is it possible to handle this on save? Believe, as above, by overriding the perform_create I should do so. And, most importantly, how can I access the model which has just been created?

For more explicit of what I am after, I would hope to do the following:

1. Create 'Order' using ViewSet above
2. Pass 'Order' (or its id, etc depending whats possible) to function populate_ing
3. populate_ing does its magic and creates other models
4. Return 'Order'

My serializer is as follows:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

In a normal Djnago view with a form, I would handle it something to the effect of:

```
def view_create_order(request):

    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        new_order = form.save()

        populate_ing(new_order)

    context = {"form": form}
    template = "order/order-update.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: You wanna call `populate_ing()` function ***only*** while creation process?

Comment: Hope would be to first create the object and then pass it to populate_ing()

Comment: so, what is the argument to the `populate_ing()` function?

Comment: Essentially the above should create an 'Order' and I want to pass that Order to the function

Comment: so, the Model class, right?

Comment: Yes. If thats possible. If not, the id of the model would suffice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191915/discussion-between-nickp-and-jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created instance will be available in **`instance`** attribute, so it can be pass to the **`populate_ing()`** function as,

```
class OrderViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # depth = 1
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        populate_ing(serializer.instance)
```